# Randomly pick words in a page and turn them into italics on JS button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, typography, italic

I'd like to create a javascript button that, when clicked on, italicizes randomly a bunch of words -- say 200 -- in a text. It means that only certain words should be in italics, but each time different ones (regardless of their function or nature -- verb, noun, subjet, preposition etc).

I was thinking of calling an array and then get "str.italics()", but that would mean that I'll have to methodically copy into the code all the words of that text, right ? Plus it seems to be non standard. I'm sure there's a prettier way to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you already have the shuffle code?

Comment: Will the text be in various parts of the DOM or contained in a single element?

Comment: The text is part of the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will randomly add italics to words in a div.  It uses a randomized array of 0 to [word count] numbers to determine which words should be italicized in the main text.

Adjust `numWordsToItalicize` to change the number of words italics are applied to.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kq2bdrpk/1/)

**Javascript**

```
var words = $('#words');
var initialText = words.html();

function italics(){  
  var wordArr = initialText.split(' ');  
  var randomArray = getRandomArray(wordArr.length);
  numWordsToItalicize = 100; 

  for(var i = 0; i < numWordsToItalicize && i < wordArr.length; i++) {
    wordArr[randomArray[i]] = '<span class="italic">' + wordArr[randomArray[i]] + '</span>';    
  }  
  words.html(wordArr.join(' '));
}

function getRandomArray(length) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) { arr.push(i); }
  return shuffleArray(arr);
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}

$('#doItalics').on('click', function(){
  italics();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="doItalics" type="button" value="Italicize!" />
<div id="words">
  A large amount of text...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have difficulties making it work though. Should the javascript be in a separate file or can i embed it in the html with the <script> tag ?

Comment: You should be able to embed it with a script tag, do you have jQuery included?  If you are getting any errors in the console when loading the page I might be able to help further.

Comment: I'll convert this into a pure js implementation quick

Comment: From the console I get :

 "TypeError: words is null" (words.html line 11 = this line : var initialText = words.innerHTML;)

My html has your vanilla js code within the script tag just after the </head> tag

Comment: Sounds like the script is running before your DOM is loaded, try wrapping that javascript in `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // code...
});`

Comment: It works like a gem. The only problem i have now it that links get considered as texts and the <a href=""> tags are displayed in the html text... but without the initial <a (This only appears on the page, as if the space in "<a " had been considered as the end of the tag... : "href="http://page.html">"

Comment: Ah yeah that might be a problem, the thing assumes the contents of that div is just raw text and splits on all spaces.  I can't actually think of a decent way to fix that at the moment :(

Comment: What about making an exception for links in the js ? Even if it forces to assign something like an id="link" to all them...

Comment: Would it be okay if none of the links were ever italicized?

Comment: Yes, I guess... There are only a few links in the text anyway.

Comment: Alright this is dumb but if you only have a few links and you don't change them much you could replace all spaces in the anchor tag with non-breaking spaces.  To type a non breaking space hold alt and type 0160 on the num pad then let go of alt.  My program splits on regular spaces (the non-breaking ones will be skipped) and should interpret your tags as a whole chuncks (it'll even wrap them in italics!)

Comment: on Bluefish i get something like that : <a&nbsp;href="https and the link is then dysfunctional...

Comment: it would maybe be better to wrap the <a... </a> in some <span id="..."></span> that would be excluded from the array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111688/discussion-between-arntjine-and-irkeninvader).